# Differential equation have no particular solution for initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Does the following diferential equation have a particular solution?

$y'=(y-1)(y+1), y(0)=1$

The general solution is: $\frac{1-e^{2x+2C}}{1+e^{2x+2C}}$

But then:

$\frac{1-e^{2C}}{1+e^{2C}}=1$

$C$ Has no solution for $\mathbb{R}$. So i would say this eq. have no particular solution. But what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in saying that there is no solution for $C$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but there *is* a solution for $y$. To see this, write $A=e^{2C}$, so your solution takes the form $$y=\frac{1-Ae^{2x}}{1+Ae^{2x}}$$
Now it's obvious that we can say the only we can say $y(0)=0$ is if we let $A=0$ (this was less obvious when we were working with $C$, since this corresponds to $C=-\infty$). This means you have the constant solution $y=1$ (and it's easy to verify this solves your equation).

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to that differential equation with that initial condition is $y(x) = 1$.